# How to select while comparing two columns from the same table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
CREATE VIEW mainT 
AS SELECT transactionId AS accountId, glbalance AS debit 
IF(totalDebit > totalCredit), glbalance as Credit IF(totalCredit > totalDebit) 
FROM `trialbalanceView`
```

Is it possible to generate this kind of query in SQL?. Please any help, 'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wanting a `CASE` statement it seems like...

```
CREATE VIEW mainT 
AS 
SELECT 
    transactionId AS accountId, 
    glbalance AS debit,
    case when totalDebit > totalCredit then glbalance else null end as Debit,
    case when totalCredit > totalDebit then glbalance else null end as Credit
FROM trialbalanceView
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try that.

Comment: @Peter88tom glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is something akin to below. I assumed that your question was in relation to conditional column(s) values based on a logical operation. If that assumption is incorrect, please provide more details on what exactly is the problem that needs solved with examples and base table data.

```
CREATE VIEW mainT 
AS 
SELECT transactionId AS accountId, 
    CASE WHEN totalDebit > totalCredit
        THEN glbalance 
    ELSE null AS debit, 
    CASE WHEN totalDebit < totalCredit
        THEN glbalance 
    ELSE null AS credit
FROM trialbalanceView
```

Thanks,
K